# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm working with AngularJS and .net core. Generally idea is with angular I'm presenting data and call WebAPI from .net core. Presenting data it is not a problem, for posting data currently I didn't finish because I have problem with showing form from where I should post.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/shared/header/header.component';
import { SpareTypeListComponent } from './components/spareType/spare-type-list/spare-type-list.component';
import { SpareTypeSummaryComponent } from './components/spareType/spare-type-summary/spare-type-summary.component';
import { SpareTypeService } from "./components/shared/spare-type.service";
import { SpareTypeFormComponent } from './components/spareType/spare-type-form/spare-type-form.component';



export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        SpareTypeListComponent,
        SpareTypeSummaryComponent,
        SpareTypeFormComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'spares', component: SpareTypeListComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ],
    providers: [ SpareTypeService ]
};
```

spare-type-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SpareType } from "../../shared/spare-type.type";
import { SpareTypeService } from '../../shared/spare-type.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'spare-form',
    templateUrl: './spare-type-form.component.html'

})

export class SpareTypeFormComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() spareType: SpareType

    constructor(private spareTypeService: SpareTypeService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    onSubmit() {

    }
}
```

spare-type-form.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #spareTypeForm="ngForm">

        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" [(ngModel)]="spareType.name" required #name="ngModel" />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Add</button>
</form>
```

[image: Error]

If i from input tag remove `[(ngModel)]="spareType.name" required #name="ngModel"` form is shown on page without any problem.
Where am I made mistake ?

I have follow this example: https://github.com/Vintharas/angular2-step-by-step-05-forms-and-validation/tree/master/src/app/person-details

Where he initialize empty object ?

Parent component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { SpareType } from '../../shared/spare-type.type';
import { SpareTypeService } from "../../shared/spare-type.service";
```

spare-type-list.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'spare-type-list',
    templateUrl: './spare-type-list.component.html',
    providers: [SpareTypeService]

})

export class SpareTypeListComponent implements OnInit {


    @Input() spareType: SpareType;

    spareTypes: SpareType[];

    constructor(private spareTypeService: SpareTypeService ) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.spareTypeService.getSpareTypes()
            .then(types => this.spareTypes = types);
    }
}
```

spare-type-list.component.html

```
<spare-form></spare-form>
<h1>Spare Types List</h1>
<p *ngIf="!spareTypes">No Spare Types Found.</p>
<spare-type-summary *ngFor="let spareType of spareTypes" [spareType]="spareType"></spare-type-summary>
```

Showing data from database is working, only I have problem with form.

Comment: you can initialize `spareType` in your component as an empty object so that it won't be `undefined` or `null` when template is rendered.

Comment: Please check my update.

Comment: I would dinitialize it in the parent component where you have the variable for your child `@Input`, i.e `spareType`.

Comment: Please check update.

Comment: Well you are not passing `spareType` to the form component in child tag. And where does this `spareType` come from, you have it as input in parent too?

Comment: @AJT_82 : it pass from here : <spare-type-summary *ngFor="let spareType of spareTypes" [spareType]="spareType"></spare-type-summary>

Comment: Yeah, but you are not passing anything to the `<spare-form>` and you shouldn't have `@Input` in parent component if that is the origin of the `spareType`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your variable **spareType** as below, it seems your view render while your object value is null hence not able to access property `name` of object `spareType`

```
@Input() spareType: SpareType = new SpareType();
```

You can also update object **ngOnChange** event.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    if (changes.spareType != null && changes.spareType.currentValue == null) {
          this.spareType=new SpareType();
    }       
}
```

**Note:** As suggested @AJT_82: "do it in the parent component" is the best approach

Comment: Here is the error:ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/app/components/spareType/spare-type-form/spare-type-form.component.ts:13:5 
    TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'SpareType'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type '{}'.

Comment: i update my code with your in spare-type-form.component.ts and problem still is present.

Comment: assign new SpareType() object when you define